# Tratar números float com vírgula e ponto separando a parte inteira da decimal

Tags: python, pandas, float

Digamos que tenho o seguinte dataframe e preciso passar a coluna `A` para ponto flutuante.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['1', '2.0', '3.000,0'],
    'B': ['a',   'b',       'c']})
```

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a |
| 1 | 2.0 | b |
| 2 | 3.000,0 | c |

Quando eu tento fazer esta operação com o `astype('float')` o Python me retorna um `ValueError` porque não é capaz de de converter o `3,0` para ponto flutuante por causa da vírgula.

```py
df.A.astype('float')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2792/3410833940.py in <module>
      5     'B': ['a',   'b',   'c']})
      6 
----> 7 df.A.astype('float')

[...]

c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
   1199     if copy or is_object_dtype(arr.dtype) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
   1200         # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
-> 1201         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
   1202 
   1203     return arr.astype(dtype, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3.000,0'
```

Sendo assim, como posso fazer esta conversão de forma automática e preservar os valores do meu dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que o o string `'3.000,0'` represente o número `3`, você pode fazer:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace(",", "").astype(float)
print(df['A'])
```

output:

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Agora, se o string `'3.000,0'` representar o número `3000`, então é mais complicado porque você tem duas notações misturadas na mesma coluna. Nesse caso o ideal seria corrigir e validar a entrada dos dados ainda na fonte, na hora em que são inseridos para sua tabela ou banco de dados, antes de chegar no Python.

Comment: Meu problema é exatamente esse, vou ter que alterar na fonte baseado em qual sinal vem primeiro se o dado possui as duas pontuações. Mas queria saber se existia algum outro jeito sem manipulações de string. Muito obrigado jfaccioni

Answer (score 0):

Depois de muito problema aparecendo criei uma função BOLADA que trata uma enorme variedade de números reais. Você pode utilizar essa função no pandas atrvés do `apply`.

```py
df['Coluna'] = df['Coluna'].apply(formata_numeros)
```

Em resumo ela faz as seguintes transformações:

```
In [1]: formata_numeros('123,456,789.1011')
Out[1]: 123456789.1011

In [2]: formata_numeros('R$ 123.456.789,1011')
Out[2]: 123456789.1011

In [3]: formata_numeros('98,99%')
Out[3]: 0.9899

In [4]: formata_numeros('98.99%')
Out[4]: 0.9899

In [5]: formata_numeros('123')
Out[5]: 123
```

A base que utilizei para criar a função foi:

1. Remover caracteres que irão me atrapalhar na conversão para int ou float, como: `'%$R°º()'`
2. Dividir o número em partes onde há ponto ou vírgula. Ou seja, o número `'123,456.789,123.999,'` resulta na seguinte lista: `['123', '456', '789', '123', '999']`
3. Realizar a seguinte concatenação: lista toda sem o último elemento (`['123', '456', '789', '123']`) + um ponto (`'.'`) + último elemento (`'999'`). Que resulta em `'123456789123.999,'`.

```
def formata_numeros(num, alphas=(), decimals=None):
    """
    Transforma em inteiro ou real dependendo do formato que o número apresentar.

    1. Parâmetros:
        - num: (str) string numérica a ser transformada
        - alphas: (iter) conjunto de caracteres que devem ser 
        removidos antes do número ser transformado em float.
        - decimal_houses: (int) representa a quantidade de casas decimais que o
        número terá ao ser retornado.
    
    2. Exemplos:
    In [1]: formata_numeros('123,456,789.1011')
    Out[1]: 123456789.1011

    In [2]: formata_numeros('R$ 123.456.789,1011')
    Out[2]: 123456789.1011

    In [3]: formata_numeros('98,99%')
    Out[3]: 0.9899
    >>> 
    """
    import re
    if num:
        num = str(num).strip()
        original = num
        percentage_pattern = re.compile("([0-9])+[,|.]([0-9])+%")
        percentage = bool(percentage_pattern.match(num))
        alphas = set((*alphas, *'%$R°º()'))
        num = ''.join([c for c in num if c not in alphas])
        num = re.split('\,|\.', num)
        try:
            if len(num) > 1: # É FLOAT
                num = float(''.join(num[:-1])+'.'+num[-1])
                if decimals and not percentage:
                    return format(num, f'.{decimals}f')
                elif decimals and percentage:
                    return format(num/100, f'.{decimals}f')
                elif not decimals and not percentage:
                    return num
                elif not decimals and percentage:
                    return num/100
            else: # É INTEIRO
                if percentage:
                    return int(''.join(num))/100
                else:
                    return int(''.join(num))
        except ValueError:
            num = ''.join(num[:-1]) + '.' + num[-1]
            raise ValueError(
                f"Não foi possível converter o número '{original}' para float")
```

Comment: A eficiência? Aparentemente é alta a complexidade do algoritmo, você chegou a fazer alguma uma analise?

Comment: Não fiz não, isso não é interessante para mim. Caso seja para você, poste seus resultados aqui para nós. A solução anterior não resolvia o meu problema. Já esta aqui pode não ser bonita e possível de escrever em uma única linha, mas resolve o que é necessário.

Comment: Além disso, expliquei a lógica que usei para resolver o problema, então quem quiser montar uma versão mais eficiente nem vai precisar partir do meu código.